# How to access other values from an OSPF packet in PyShark

Tags: python, pyshark

I would like to access values from LS Update Packet (Numbers of LSA, types, etc ), but it seems i'm stuck. I tried both options, for loop and apply on capture, i still cannot get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you want to process the values that you are seeking.

The code below will allow you to query and extract OSPF information from a `pcap` file using `pyshark.FileCapture`.  You can do the same thing using `pyshark.LiveCapture`

The `pcap' file that I used is from [Wireshark sample captures](https://wiki.wireshark.org/SampleCaptures)

```
import pyshark

capture = pyshark.FileCapture('hsrp-and-ospf-in-LAN')
for packet in capture:
    if hasattr(packet, 'ospf'):
        field_names = packet.ospf._all_fields
        for field_name in field_names:
            print(field_name)
            
            # output snippet
            ospf.lsa.age
            ospf.lsa.donotage
            ospf.v2.options
            ospf.v2.options.dn
            ospf.v2.options.o
            ospf.v2.options.dc
            ospf.v2.options.l
            ospf.v2.options.n
            ospf.v2.options.mc
            ospf.v2.options.e
            ospf.v2.options.mt
            ospf.lsa
            ospf.lsa.summary
            ospf.lsa.id
            ospf.advrouter
            ospf.lsa.seqnum
            ospf.lsa.chksum
            ospf.lsa.length
    print('\n')
```

You can get the `field values` using this:

```
import pyshark

capture = pyshark.FileCapture('hsrp-and-ospf-in-LAN')
for packet in capture:
    if hasattr(packet, 'ospf'):
        field_names = packet.ospf._all_fields
        field_values = packet.ospf._all_fields.values()
        for field_name in field_names:
            for field_value in field_values:
                print(f'Field Name:{field_name} -- Field Value: {field_value}')
    print('\n')
```

Again I don't know how you want to filter.  Below is one way to filter the `LSA packet` information.

```
import pyshark

capture = pyshark.FileCapture('hsrp-and-ospf-in-LAN')
for packet in capture:
    if hasattr(packet, 'ospf'):
        field_names = packet.ospf._all_fields
        field_values = packet.ospf._all_fields.values()
        for field_name in field_names:
            if 'lsa' in field_name:
                for field_value in field_values:
                    print(f'Field Name:{field_name} -- Field Value: {field_value}')
    print('\n')
```

Here is a document that I wrote on using [PyShark for packet analysis](https://github.com/johnbumgarner/pyshark_packet_analysis)